# Are there any possible pitfalls/issues that can arise from URL rewrites?

Tags: url-rewriting, canonical-url

I'm in the process of move a website for a client, utilizing a new theme. Usually this is straightforward enough but some of the base *category* URLs they use are mess and they would also like to be able to change some of the names of those categories also.

I know fixing/changing these URLs can be accomplished using a 301 rewrite but I am wondering if there is a possibility of any issues arising from doing so.

The client is overly anxious about broken links and loss of ranking and I want to put my own mind at peace about the changes (granted I know that modifying URLs may affect ranking).

Also part of the change will be setting the site with a prefix of `www` - I'm assuming the same concerns apply.

Comment: problems may arise and it'd help us if you show us the .htaccess current and after

Comment: Once I have the latter worked up I will post them.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the problems that can arise happen when the implementation has bugs.  I've seen plenty of bugs that cause SEO issues.

- Circular redirects
- Missed files that go 404 rather than redirecting
- Syntax errors in htaccess that cause 500 server errors
- noindex tags applied to far more pages than intended
- Coding errors that cause nearly blank pages to render to Googlebot

Really there is no end to what *can* go wrong.

When implemented correctly, url changes that you are proposing should be very painless from an SEO perspective.  I would recommend lots of QA on this type of change.  Make sure you have a list of urls that will change.  Hit them with a crawler (like curl) to make sure their status is correct and the redirect location is what you expect.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can post the contents of the files? I assume I can't simply post them in my question?